# add existing pdfs to fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, web, fpdf

Is there any function that I could call in order to include an existing pdf in my `fpdf` file?

For example

```
$pdf->AddPage(from file example.pdf);
```

something like that? is it posible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

fpdi is what you are looking for - see http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/

Comment: thnx.. i think thats it ... although i get this error: Warning: require_once(fpdf_tpl.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream help...

Comment: you have to download both fpdi and fpdf_tpl (as stated here: http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/downloads/)

Comment: thnx! whats a simple code to be able to add existing pdfs to my fpdf; because lets say I already have 2 pages inside my fpdf... using the code from fpdi it just overwrites both pages and makes only 1... any idea?

Comment: import_page takes the number of the page to import as the first argument - simply import a second template for page 2 and use that on a new page

Comment: thnx! you are so much help!!!!!  ... one last question :D ... is there any way to center text in the page? (in - $pdf->SetXY)because I have some $_POST arguments and dont know the exact length of wordr, so I have to make a default center for them... know how?

Comment: thnx for responding! ... but there is no cell here: $pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',12); 
 $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0); 
 $pdf->SetXY(80, 400); 
 $pdf->Write(0, "".$person["ED"]);